# How to find the fundamental matrix for this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

I have the following differential equation:
$$t^2x''(t)-4tx'(t)+6x(t)=0$$
and two linearly independent solutions, $x_1(t)=t^2$ and $x_2(t)=t^3$ in the interval $(0, \infty )$. I'm then asked to find the fundamental matrix for $$A(t)=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 \\
-6t^{-1} & 4t^{-1} \\
 \end{array} \right)$$
I know how to find the fundamental matrix when an equation is in the form $y'(t)=A(t)y(t)$ but can't see how to put this into that form. Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: @Mathlovin This is taken directly from the question and when they're subbed in they work out right. Can I ask where the error comes from?

Comment: If you divide by $t^2$ and then write the second order system as two first order systems, the term should be $-6t^{-2}$. I agree with everything else as stated. Was this posted correctly?

Comment: Yes, definitely posted correctly. Maybe there's an error in the original question

Comment: My bad. Made a mistake in my own calculations. Those solutions are correct.

Comment: How about matrix $A$? Is it in the form
$$
\left ( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\ -6t^{-2} & 4t^{-1}
\end{array} \right )
$$
by a chance?